# Given a non-empty array of integers, return the third maximum number in this array. If it does not exist, return the maximum number.(Java)

Tags: java

For a given array input,the output should be the third maximum number from the list of numbers provided by the user.
Example 1:
Input: [3, 2, 1]

Output: 1

Explanation: The third maximum is 1.
Example 2:
Input: [1, 2]

Output: 2
 I have shared my code below along with the comments.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThirdLargest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int max = 0;
    /*To get the length of the array from the user*/
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the length of the array");

    int length = sc.nextInt();
    int[] myArray = new int[length];

    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array:");
    /*Adding the numbers provided by the user as an array*/
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        myArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
    /*trying to get the maximum number from the array*/
    for (int i = 0; i + 1 < length - 1; i++) {
        if (myArray[i] < myArray[i + 1]) {
            /*Storing the maximum number in temp*/
            temp = myArray[i + 1];
        } else
            temp = myArray[i];
        /*Trying to get the second maximum number from the array and storing it in temp2*/
        if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1] && myArray[i] < temp)
            temp2 = myArray[i];
        /*Trying to get the third maximum number from the array and storing it as max*/
        if (myArray[i] > myArray[i + 1] && myArray[i] < temp && myArray[i] < temp2)
            max = myArray[i];
        System.out.println(max);
    }
}}
```

My result is:

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8bCQ.png)

I am getting the result as 0 and 0. I should actually get 2. Please help.

Comment: Are you allowed to sort the elements of the array in ascending order and then getting the 3rd last element?

Comment: Yes, It's possible

Comment: I would do that :)

Comment: I changed my code and I got the output.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the output as text into the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

import java.util.Scanner;

public class ThirdLargest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    int temp = 0;
    int temp2 = 0;
    int max = 0;
    /*To get the length of the array from the user*/
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the length of the array");

    int length = sc.nextInt();
    int[] myArray = new int[length];

    System.out.println("Enter the elements of the array:");
    /*Adding the numbers provided by the user as an array*/
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        myArray[i] = sc.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
            if (myArray[i] > myArray[j]) {
                temp = myArray[i];
                myArray[i] = myArray[j];
                myArray[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(myArray[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to sort the array to do this.  It can be done in O(n) time by checking relative values as you iterate once thru the list.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rr = new Random();
        int[] a = rr.ints(10, 1, 100).toArray();

        // descending order

        int first = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int second = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        int third = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int v : a) {
            if (first < v) {
                third = second;
                second = first;
                first = v;
            } else if (second < first && second < v) {
                third = second;
                second = v;
            } else if (third < v) {
                third = v;
            }
        }
        int len = a.length;
        System.out.println(len > 2 ? "Third largest = " + third :
                len > 1 ? "Second largest = " + second :
                "Largest = " + first);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
    }
```